# No WiFi adapter Found Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: networking, drivers

I recently installed Ubuntu 19.04 in my HPw2007v. when I tried the live version I could use wifi connection, but now that it is installed when I try to connect it says that No WiFi Adapter found.
This is `sudo lshw -c network` output:

```
*-network                 
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
   logical name: enp2s0
   version: 02
   serial: 00:24:8c:5c:57:ff
   capacity: 1Gbit/s
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8168 driverversion=8.046.00-NAPI latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
   resources: irq:18 ioport:e800(size=256) memory:febff000-febfffff memory:f8ff0000-f8ffffff memory:febc0000-febdffff


*-network
   description: Ethernet interface
   physical id: 1
   bus info: usb@2:2
   logical name: enp0s29f7u2c4i2
   serial: 1a:65:90:89:fa:6e
   capabilities: ethernet physical
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ipheth ip=172.20.10.9 link=yes multicast=yes
```

Comment: The info you posted seems to be from the ethernet cable card and not wifi, please post the wifi identification or the full lspci output